# Scatter Plot using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, remote-sensing, landsat-8, scatterplot

I m using a study area which has 3 feature in it, namely cloud, snow and land. I want a scatter plot between Brightness temperature of band10(BT10) and Brightness temperature of band11(BT11). I m getting a plot but how can I add this feature on plots (for example: the plot is in single color now(in my code), the plot can be in 3 different colors indicating 3 features) so that all the features variation can be visualized[image: scatter plot obtained using below code].

my study area: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?asset=users/keerthana_Nagesh/Bagirathi

code follows:

```
Map.addLayer(table);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
var image = l8.filterDate('2016-03-18', '2016-03-19')
            .filterBounds(table)
            .median()          
            .clip(table);
            
// RGB
var rgb = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4
};
Map.addLayer(image, rgb, 'rgb image');

//SWIR 
var swir = {
  bands: ['B6', 'B4', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4
};
Map.addLayer(image, swir, 'SWIR image');

// Band 10, Brightness Temperature
var BT10 = image.expression(
  '(1321.08/(log((774.89)/((0.0003342*DN)+0.1+1))))',
  {
    DN : image.select('B10')
  }).rename('BT10');

print(BT10);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["BT10"],
                     "min":220,
                     "max":225,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.centerObject(BT10);
Map.addLayer(BT10, imageVisParam, 'BT-10');

// Band 11, Brightness Temperature
var BT11 = image.expression(
  '(1201.14/(log((480.89)/((0.0003342*(DN))+0.1+1))))',
  {
    DN : image.select('B11')
  }).rename('BT11');

print(BT11);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                    "bands":["BT11"],
                    "min":215,
                    "max":225,
                    "gamma":1};

Map.centerObject(BT11);
Map.addLayer(BT11, imageVisParam, 'BT-11');

var combined = BT10.addBands(BT11);
var imageVisParam = {
                    "min":215,
                    "max":225,
                    "gamma":1};
Map.centerObject(combined);
Map.addLayer(combined, imageVisParam, 'combined');

// sample N points from the 2-band image
var values = combined.sample({ region: table, scale: 30, numPixels: 1000, geometries: true}) 
Map.addLayer(values.style({ color: 'red', pointSize: 2 }), {}, 'samples')



// // plot sampled features as a scatter chart
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(values, 'BT10', ['BT11'])
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({ pointSize: 2, pointColor: 'red', width: 300, height: 300, titleX: 'BAND10', titleY: 'BAND11' })
   
print(chart)
```

Comment: Your study area only seems to contain a single feature: `print(ee.FeatureCollection('users/keerthana_Nagesh/Bagirathi').size())`. Also, please update your question and add a link to the script in the Code Editor (use the `Get Link` button).

Comment: i have attached a code link below, https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/87eee4bd54374bfb3c7b8d2f48d4db2f. i had attached the study area shapefile link in my question. you can create feature collection of your choice(cloud, snow, land) and create a scatter plot for all three feature in one plot.